# Syntax Error from Windres.exe when creating Dialog Template

Tags: winapi, dialog, mingw32

I am writing a win32 application with the following code in `Recourse.rc`

```
IDD_DLGFIRST DIALOG 260, 200, 188, 95
STYLE DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Win32 Programming"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg"
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK", IDOK, 130, 10, 50, 14
END
```

When I try to compiler the following code with MinGW, `Windres.exe` gives me an error on the second line

Comment: I just says: syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was.
I forgot to #include windows.h for the style macros.